# JBoss "JPA Entites from Tables" not creating annotated POJO class

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I'm having an odd problem using JBoss tools within Eclipse.

I want to use the reverse engineering feature to generate a POJO class with JPA Annotations. I right-click the relevant package and choose New -> "JPA Entities from Tables "and I go through the wizard. I have set up my PostgreSQL connection properly and I can see my tables in my database and I choose the particular one that I want to use to generate a POJO. I can even modify the columns that I want and their mapped field names.

However, after I click "Finish" there is NO POJO created in the package or anywhere in the project. But persistence.xml is updated with a class reference to the missing class.

For example, I have a table called Users, I'm expecting to create a POJO called User.java but it does not get created. Hoever, persistence.xml has a new line org.example.model.User

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Eclipse and JBoss Tools version? If the problem persists try JBoss Developer Studio as a test.

Comment: Also open the Error Log view and see if an exception occurs when you click finish on the wizard.